# Como transformar um valor numérico em FORMATO DE MOEDA (Real Brasileiro) no SELECT MYSQL

Tags: mysql, number-format

Olá, Sucesso e paz a todos!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lancamentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes_referencia` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(32,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao_lancamento` text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17253 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `lancamentos` (`id`, `data`, `mes_referencia`, `cliente`, `valor`, `descricao_lancamento`) VALUES
(1, '2021-01-07', 'Janeiro', 'João', '350.40', 'Entrada do João'),
(2, '2020-01-08', 'Janeiro', 'José', '760.30', 'Entrada do José');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pagamentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes_referencia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12758 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `pagamentos` (`id`, `data`, `mes_referencia`, `valor`, `conta`, `descricao`) VALUES
(1, '2021-10-08', 'Janeiro','300', 'Bradesco', 'Descrição do pagamento'),
(2, '2021-10-08', 'Janeiro','400', 'Caixa', 'Descrição do pagamento');
```

Faço o select assim:

```
SELECT (
    (SELECT SUM(`valor`) AS Total
    FROM `lancamentos`)
    -
    (SELECT SUM(`valor`) AS Total
    FROM `pagamentos`)
  )As Total
```

E tenho esse resultado **410.7**

Como Obtenho esse: **R$ 410,70** ??

[Código] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d67c6aa/1

Grata!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz dessa maneira:

```
SELECT res.Total, 
CONCAT('R$ ' , FORMAT(res.Total, 2, 'de_DE')) AS Valor
FROM (
SELECT (
    (SELECT SUM(`valor`) AS Total
    FROM `lancamentos`)
    -
    (SELECT SUM(`valor`) AS Total
    FROM `pagamentos`)
)As Total ) res
```

Código completo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d67c6aa/12

Answer (score 3):

O banco de dados armazena "números", se quer mostrar num outro formato pode fazer isso depois, com alguma linguagem de programação, para exibir num relatório ou página.

Se ainda precisar formatar a nível da query no banco, pode usar a [função format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format), passando as casas decimais e a cultura:

```
select FORMAT(410.7, 2, 'pt_BR')
```

Veja funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/194910)

Se quiser o prefixo monetário, só concatenar assim:

```
 select CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(410.7, 2, 'pt_BR'));
```